# a native query to trigger a table lock using SQL (Postgres)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, locking

I would like to make sure that the whole table is locked during my JPA transaction.
As far as i could figure out, there is no JPA Locking Mode to lock the whole table.
My question is, how does a proper Locking Statement look like and how can i combine it with entity managers merge or persist operations?

Comment: `lock table in exclusive mode` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html

Comment: And the lock will get automagicly released when JPA commits its transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Actually thanks to the comment the solution was following statement:

```
getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("LOCK TABLE schemaname.tablename").executeUpdate();
```

The lock will get removed then the transaction (also the one from hibarnate - actually its the same) is over.